# Wait for database connection in Spring Boot without an exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, mariadb

I want to create a microservice with Spring Boot. For persistence i use a mariadb database. To wait for the database which is running in a docker container, i implemented the following code like shown [here](https://deinum.biz/2020-06-30-Wait-for-database-startup/):

```
@Bean
    public DatabaseStartupValidator databaseStartupValidator(DataSource dataSource) {
        var dsv = new DatabaseStartupValidator();
        dsv.setDataSource(dataSource);
        dsv.setTimeout(60);
        dsv.setInterval(7);
        dsv.setValidationQuery(DatabaseDriver.MYSQL.getValidationQuery());
        return dsv;
    }
```

The code is working very well, my application is now waiting for the database connection. But i get an exception at startup of the application:

```
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to Host ....
...
...
...
```

In the next line i get an information, that it will wait for the database:

`021-04-07 21:29:40.816  INFO 16569 --- [           main] o.s.j.support.DatabaseStartupValidator   : Database has not started up yet - retrying in 7 seconds (timeout in 57.65 seconds)`

After that the application is starting as expected. So i think everything is working fine, but what i have to do to suppress the Exception? In the linked [article](https://deinum.biz/2020-06-30-Wait-for-database-startup/) it should work without an exception. Do i have to implement the "dependsOnPostProcessor" function? Which dependency i have to use? Sorry, possible a dumb question, i am new to spring boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get rid of that exception you can state the below directive in your `application.properties` file:

```
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=OFF
```

Keep in mind that if the application will not be able to get in contact with the db your spring crashes after a while due to that exception. In addition the above directive prevent you to see any logging activity related to Hikari.

In summary you hide the *appearance* of the exception until it is possible before the application dies due to timeout.

hoping I clarified a bit the case

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed you need to add the "depends-on" for the beans that rely on the data source. Note the following part of the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/DatabaseStartupValidator.html):

> To be referenced via "depends-on" from beans that depend on database startup, like a Hibernate SessionFactory or custom data access objects that access a DataSource directly.

If I understand it well, this means that beans such as an `EntityManagerFactory` which rely on the database will now have to go through the `DatabaseStartupValidator` bean and wait for the DB startup. I don't know what caused your exception, but usually there is an `EntityManagerFactory` involved, so try adding the DependsOn on this object at least.

This is how the linked article is doing it:

```
@Bean
public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor dependsOnPostProcessor() {
    return bf -> {
        // Let beans that need the database depend on the DatabaseStartupValidator
        // like the JPA EntityManagerFactory or Flyway
        String[] flyway = bf.getBeanNamesForType(Flyway.class);
        Stream.of(flyway)
                .map(bf::getBeanDefinition)
                .forEach(it -> it.setDependsOn("databaseStartupValidator"));

        String[] jpa = bf.getBeanNamesForType(EntityManagerFactory.class);
        Stream.of(jpa)
                .map(bf::getBeanDefinition)
                .forEach(it -> it.setDependsOn("databaseStartupValidator"));
    };
}
```

You may not necessarily have `Flyway` configured, but the main thing to note is the dependency itself is referenced by the bean name `databaseStartupValidator` which is the name of the method that creates the bean.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have now implemented the "dependsOnPostProcessor" function as a test (but just with EntityManagerFactory). 

But nothing changes. I still get the exception.